# Pesquisa de valor exato ou aproximado em vetor desordenado em C

Tags: c, array

Estou tentando escrever um algoritmo em C que lê um valor inteiro N e um vetor de 10 posições. Que busque o valor dentro do vetor, se existir informar a posição, porém se não existir, encontrar o valor mais próximo existente. Estou tendo dificuldades em terminar o código, principalmente na parte de encontrar o valor mais próximo e não sei onde estou errando:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  
    int i, n, vetor[10], posicao, diferenca, menorDiferenca, prox;

    printf("N: "); 
    scanf("%i", &n);
    printf("Vetor: "); 
    
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    menorDiferenca = abs(n - vetor[0]);
    
        scanf("%i", &vetor[i]);
            if (vetor[i] == n){
                posicao = i;
                printf("\nposicao: %i", posicao);
                break;
            }
            else{
                diferenca = abs(n - vetor[i]);
                if (diferenca <= menorDiferenca){
                    prox = vetor[i];
                }
            }
                
    }


printf("\nvalor prox: %i", prox);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Teste o menorDiferenca = abs(n - vetor[0]); antes do for, creio ser isto.

Comment: https://ideone.com/fPvT6D

Answer (score -4):

Bom, sou um pouco iniciante em C, mas construi a base de um algoritmo de acordo com o problema que você pede.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

const int TAMANHO = 10;
void main(){
    //Declarando vetor
    int vet[TAMANHO];
    //Declarando Variaveis
    int i, n, k, posicao, maior = 0, menor = 0, maiorNumero = 0;
    
    //loop pra ler os numeros do array
    for(i=0; i<TAMANHO; i++){
        printf("Insira um numero:");
        scanf("%d", &vet[i]);
    }
    
    //Quebra linhas
    printf("\n");
    
    //ler N
    printf("N: "); 
    scanf("%d", &n); //N é o numero que o usuario saber se ha no array 
    
    //loop para saber o maior numero do array
    for(i=0; i<TAMANHO;i++){
        if(maiorNumero < vet[i]){
            maiorNumero = vet[i];
        }
    }  
    
    //loop quando o numero esta dentro do array 
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if(n == vet[i]){
            printf("O numero %d esta no vetor na posicao %d", n);
        }            
    }
    
     // Variáveis para armazenar os números mais próximos
    int numeroProximoMaior = -1;
    int numeroProximoMenor = -1;

    // Loop para encontrar os números mais próximos
    for (k = 1; k <= maiorNumero; k++) {
        for (i = 0; i < TAMANHO; i++) {
            //pega o valor n e soma k.
            maior = n + k;
            //pega o valor n e subtrai k.
            menor = n - k;

            if (maior == vet[i]) {
                numeroProximoMaior = maior;
            } else if (menor == vet[i]) {
                numeroProximoMenor = menor;
            }
        }
        // Se ambos os números próximos forem encontrados, pare o loop
        if (numeroProximoMaior != -1 && numeroProximoMenor != -1) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Verificando se foram encontrados números próximos e imprimindo os resultados
    if (numeroProximoMaior != -1) {
        printf("O numero mais proximo maior que %d no vetor e: %d.\n", n, numeroProximoMaior);
    }
    if (numeroProximoMenor != -1) {
        printf("O numero mais proximo menor que %d no vetor e: %d.\n", n, numeroProximoMenor);
    }
        

    getch();
}
```

Na última parte do código, a openIa me ajudou a terminar.

Comment: [Conteúdo gerado por ChatGPT não é permitido na rede](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8842/137387)

Comment: Assim como expliquei no final da linha, as ultimas 2 linhas foram geradas pela openIA. O resto foi produzido e pensado por mim.

Comment: Qual a parte de **Conteúdo gerado por ChatGPT não é permitido na rede** você não entendeu?

Comment: Isso mostra como o ChatGPT ainda está longe do ideal, pelo menos como gerador de código. Dá pra fazer de forma muito mais simples: https://ideone.com/fPvT6D - Independente disso, o código está errado (mais um motivo pra não confiar no ChatGPT, tem que conferir tudo que ele responde). Teste, por exemplo, com os números `2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 23, 3, 15` e busque pelo número `18`. Seu código vai imprimir tanto o 23 quanto o 15 (sendo que somente o 15 deveria ser mostrado).

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pela reflexão.